# Display paging control with white dots on the top android

Tags: android

I want to display this type of paging control as shown in the image i am getting the length of string array and i want to display the length as paging control with white dots as the number of pages.please help

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [this](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) is what you need

or [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).

It is called ViewPagerIndicatior and usually it is used on conjuction with ViewPager (of course you can use it also alone).

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok let me check but i want to make project in 2.2 or later so will it be useful

Comment: these libraries support 2.2 :)

Comment: ok but how to use it can u please elaborate as i am new to it

Comment: It has an example that show. In a few words, you have to add the code to your project, and then add the View to your layout also. It is just a View like others.

Comment: as addressed by u i tried to import the project by downloading it but it shows error in all classes please help

Comment: Did you add the jar library to your build path?

Comment: i am unable to import the library please help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10036/discussion-between-user1266179-and-dimitris-makris)

Comment: is this still valid as of 5.0 ?